# Retrieving CSR cache information for printer [Printer Name] failed

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-event-log, printer

We've recently implemented a print server, which are a bunch of printers (a mixture of xerox and hp printers). For drivers, we used global drivers, and specific driver for that printer. The printers deployed via group policy. Users access by logging in through RD gateway to RDS farm.

after deployment, users sometimes get a bunch of these errors (one for each printer) in the event viewer whenever they login, and the printer enough either says not connected, or that the printer driver is missing when the try to print, or the print job is stuck in queue. the printers still shows, but they can't print. what is weird about this is it only happens to 1 or 2 printers. The rest can print.

In event viewer, under printservice, it will show this message, "Retrieving CSR cache information for printer [printer name] failed. error code 0x2. See the event user data for context information". I could find any pattern or reason as to why this happen, as it doesn't happen to a specific user, nor it occurs in a specific RDS sever, nor it is happening to a specific printer.

I have tried removing all the printers and drivers, redeploying them, clearing spooler from our RDS servers, and it still persist.

I was wondering if any Windows Server Expert have encounter this problem, knows what the cause is, and knows what i can do to fix this?
PS. all our server runs on Server 2012 R2.

Below is the XML of the event error (replace some names and ids with [whatever]).

Thanks.

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 - <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-PrintService" Guid="{747EF6FD-E535-4D16-B510-42C90F6873A1}" /> 
    <EventID>221</EventID> 
    <Version>0</Version> 
    <Level>2</Level> 
    <Task>21</Task> 
    <Opcode>12</Opcode> 
    <Keywords>0x4000000000000022</Keywords> 
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-03-06T16:52:14.271654000Z" /> 
    <EventRecordID>860765</EventRecordID> 
    <Correlation /> 
    <Execution ProcessID="31380" ThreadID="40628" /> 
    <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational</Channel> 
    <Computer>[Server Name]</Computer> 
    <Security UserID=[User ID] /> 
    </System>
    - <UserData>
    - <SpoolerGenericEvent xmlns="http://manifests.microsoft.com/win/2005/08/windows/printing/spooler/core/events">
    <Label>EnumeratePrinterEntries</Label> 
    <ErrorCode>0x2</ErrorCode> 
    <ObjectName>[Printer Name]</ObjectName> 
    </SpoolerGenericEvent>
    </UserData>
    </Event>
```